musl + backtrace support
My software has a signal handler returning a backtrace for easy troubleshooting. I recently decided to move from glibc to musl libc to be able to easily provide all-static binaries that can run even on very old Linux systems. I compile within alpine:latest docker containers.
Everything works nicely except for backtracing, which is not natively supported by musl. So I tried to use

libexecinfo,
libbacktrace, and
libunwind

They all "work" only sort-of in the sense that a manual backtrace generation always works, however, the most important bit does not: generating a backtrace within a signal handler.
The exact same code compiled in the alpine:latest container:
  /work/app/src/signals.c:53 in signal_handler() [0x42645c]
  src/signal/x86_64/restore.s:1 in ???() [0x8019df]

and once on the Ubuntu host (using the same library for backtracing!):
  /home/d/app/src/signals.c:53 in signal_handler() [0x56d935e2bed4]
  ./signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libc_sigaction.c:0 in ???() [0x7dd5ee04531f]
  /home/d/app/src/args.c:50 in parse_args() [0x56d935e0d652]
  /home/d/app/src/main.c:15 in main() [0x56d935e080fe]
  ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58 in __libc_start_call_main() [0x7dd5ee02a1c9]
  ../csu/libc-start.c:360 in __libc_start_main_impl() [0x7dd5ee02a28a]
  (null):0 -> (null)() [0x56d935e08374]
  (null):0 -> (null)() [0xffffffffffffffff]

I expect src/args.c:50 because that's the location where my intentional "test crash" is.
The binary compiled inside the container returns the same when run on the host so it indeed seems that the reason lies within musl libc's signal handler. Even when I use the third argument to the signal handler as context for libbacktrace, the result is still the same.
Any idea how I could obtain a "proper" backtrace with musl libc?

Adding a small [MCVE], like main() signal(handle_siguser1, SIGUSR1); raise(SIGUSR1); } void handle_sigusr1() { print_backtrace() } will greatly help others reproduce the problems.
